# Is there a way to create a mutable list in a class statement? (Python 3x)

Tags: python-3.x

So in creating a class, I noticed that I was unable to append any elements for my list in the class. Is there a way to append and arrange the order of elements in the list I create in the class statement?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, bar):
         self.__bar = []

    def input_method(self):
         self.__bar.append()

    def return_bar(self)
         return self.__bar

candy = Foo()
```

Is there a way for me to append an element into self.__bar?

Comment: `self.bar` and `self.__bar` are not the same objects

Comment: Why are you ignoring the bar argument that you receive in `def __init__(self, bar):`. Instead you are creating a new empty list in `bar =[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually append *something* to the list in your appending method:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
         self.__bar = []

    def input_method(self, something):
         self.__bar.append(something)

    def return_bar(self):
         return self.__bar

candy = Foo()
```

Now it seems good to me:

```
>>> candy.input_method('helloo')
>>> candy.return_bar()
['helloo']
```

---

Note that since you weren't using (or sending) the `bar` argument to the `__init__` method, I omitted it from my answer (just warning you)!